# Moore-Penrose Pseudo inverse of a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a $n\times 1 $ vector and two vectors are independent.

Define $X^+$ as Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.

and let $I_n$ is $n \times n $ identity matrix and $P_{X_1} = X_1(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^T$.

Then can I expand $((I_n - P_{X_1})X_2)^+$ in closed form?

First, I thought

\begin{align}
((I_n - P_{X_1})X_2)^+ &= X_2^+(I_n-P_{X_1})^+ \\
&=(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}(I_n-P_{X_1})
\end{align}

but then I realized that $(AB)^+ \neq B^+A^+$.

Comment: The Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a column vector $v$ is just $\frac{v^\ast}{\|v\|_2^2}$ when $v\ne0$ or zero otherwise. In your case put $v=(I_n-P_{X_1})X_2$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks. I understood